# jQuery in parent

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue pushing my code through into the parent window. It's currently in an iFrame and I've been ratteling my brain over this for some time. I have very little experience with parent functions. Any help would be great, Thanks!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a[rel*=2gain]").facebox({
           loadingImage : 'rc/loading.gif',
           closeImage   : 'rc/closelabel.png'
      });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry if it was vague, I was asking if anybody knew how I could pass the code into a parent window.

Comment: You're not clear on what it is you're trying to accomplish. Which page contains the code in your question? What is the name of the function in the parent document that you're trying to call, and what have you tried without success?

Comment: You've accepted an answer (Gabe's), but you also commented that the help was not what you needed/did not work. Is this the correct answer or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `parent.document`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(parent.document).find("a[rel*=2gain]").facebox({
           loadingImage : 'rc/loading.gif',
           closeImage   : 'rc/closelabel.png'
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to operate from the context of the parent's document and jQuery object.

**From IFRAME**

```
$(function() {
    var $p = window.parent.$;
    $p("a[rel*=2gain]").facebox({
           loadingImage : 'rc/loading.gif',
           closeImage   : 'rc/closelabel.png'
      });
});
```